# get RamMap "processes" table in PowerShell

Tags: memory, powershell

SysInternals' RamMap has a "Processes" table:

[image: 2024-01-10 V11-Encor RamMap - Processes]

Possible to get this table (or anything resembling it, allowing to attribute "Page Table" usage to specific entities) via PowerShell?

(Related question and context: [PowerShell: what's responsible for large "page table" in Windows?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1151328/powershell-whats-responsible-for-large-page-table-in-windows))

P.S. SysInternals [Handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) and [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) (aka "ProcMon") can output this information, including via CLI, making it possible to, say, create a CSV table with the needed info. The question however focuses on doing it in PowerShell and necessary system calls vs. any external utilities.

Comment: You can run ProcMon from a PowerShell window the same way you would from a CMD window. Have you tried doing this? If so, how does that fail to meet your needs?

Comment: sysinternals handle does (meet the needs) - yet because we want to collect this info on multiple remote systems, the ideal way to do this is via PS and system calls only, w/o resorting to any external utilities - see the "P.S." in the question...

Comment: Can you specify the information that RamMap gives that Get-Process does not provide? You appear to be asking us to read between a lot of lines here.

Comment: Also, to address a comment you left on the answer I deleted: RAMMap's Processes tab shows information on running processes.  To address the other comment: The Get-Processes cmdlet does return something "resembling it". You have failed so far to specify precisely what information you require, have expected us to make broad assumptions and do a lot of further study to guess at information you should have included in your question. Please EDIT your question to make it more clear.

Comment: wish there was a way to block abusive users... unsure how to answer? move on to the next question. Question seems vague? Pass. Unfamiliar terms, unfamiliar with the topic of Windows memory management, need to brush up on what handles are? **Definitely** stay out, and don't try to answer - as opposed to blaming everything on the asker. SMH.